# share a string between view and controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a String variable which is defined and initialized in a View. In fact, its value is determined by a few buttons.
This value is then saved by the controller in the database
But I do not know how to send this String from view to controller

Answer (score 0):

There are i believe two ways to do that, one will be to Bind it in controller (HttpPost).Or you can "Request" value by name.

Look up offical MVC tutorial from MS for Binding. 
About request you can look up this one : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/getting-data-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

how to share a string value between view and controller .in MVC
this string is initialized in view.then this string passed to controller
this string is initialized by multi bottoms.
this is a string and not a Html.Label or not a Html.TextBox
Similar
 @{string STR = ""; }